# Automated Putty Program?

Tags: centos, putty, vps

I have multiple Linux vps's and I need to be able to run a program that executes a command on the servers at the same time, or with minor delay. If someone could point my in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can run a task in the background by appending `&` after the command. I would write a script to execute the command on the different servers:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in server1.domain server2.domain server3.domain
do
    ssh username@$server "mycommand params"&
done
```

This is for manual execution of a task on a number of remote machines. Of course, you will need to be using public key authentication (not password) otherwise it will hang on the password prompt.

If instead you meant that you want a regularly scheduled task to run on each individual machine, use cron as another answer suggested.